# Why am I getting different outputs when running these 2 Select statements at one click compared to running them separately?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running `SQL Server 2012` and I have a table on the database called `CtyRes`.
This table has only 2 columns: `ResaID` and `CountryCode`.
The table has `172260` rows (or records).

I have the following query in `SSMS`:

```
Select count (*) from CtyRes

Select ResaID from CtyRes
```

When I execute the query in one click, output for first Select Statement is `172,260` and output for the second Select Statement is `172,261`.

However, when I run them separately, output for both Select statements are 172,260

I have checked and there are no duplicate `ResaID` in the `CtyRes` table.
Why am I getting these different results?

Comment: Because there is no separator `;` between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a set of select queries sql-server counts all rows from all result tabs so you get the sum of them, however when you click on one of the results you get the count just for this tab. So if you click on the result of the second query you should get `172260`.

Comment: That's brilliant. Never thought about it. I was just looking at the output figure on the bottom right of output window and thought that it was related to the output of the second select statement!